# MVC: How do I create link on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to pass link to view from controller. Is there anything like `Html.ActionLink` on the server side?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Html.ActionLink` _is_ server side. Please refine the question.

Comment: I'm going to use it from controller. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to pass a url or perhaps a route to the view as part of the `Model` parameter?

Comment: In the view it now looks like `<%: Html.ActionLink(supply.SupplyName, "Edit", new { id = supply.ID })%>`. I want to pass it through `Model`. Like `Model.MyLink`

Comment: hey i'm not sure you can do that there. The `LinkExtensions` needs the view context which you wont have at the controller point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controller you can use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper_methods.aspx) to generate a new url using actions, controllers and routevalues.

This will not return a `<a>` tag, but only the url, for you to use in your controller.